# JSON is printing in the console but returns undefined when accessing value of a key

Tags: reactjs, flask, socket.io, react-suspense

I'm not sure how to modify the `useEffect` function (or use React's new `Suspense` component) to wait for all of the data to load in before rendering the components.

Here is the code that brings in the data from a Flask Backend:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";

const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.emit('test', {"name": "jim"})
    socket.on("test_client", data => {
      setResponse(data);
    }));
  }, []);
```

Here is the code that console.log's the JSON:

`<p>Data: {console.log(props.data)}</p>`

This returns the JSON in the console:

```
{content: {…}}
content:
     exchanges: (3) ["Deribit", "bybit", "BitMEX"]
     user_data: (10) [1, "testuser", "testuser", 
      "$5$rounds=535000$obwWzc1uoSI4MMFT$YruKioA8n321NDsX1UHXGtiY8rgfsBD.5z17kZ1UOnD", 
      "test@dwm.fund", "DWM", "United States", {…}, "1597353995233", 3]
     __proto__: Object
     __proto__: Object
```

When trying `<p>Data: {console.log(props.data.content.user_data[1])}</p>`, it returns the error `Can't find property user_data of undefined.`

I tried using the new `Suspense` component in React by wrapping my components in `return` with it, but I still received the same error.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi, perhaps content is missing or there are multiple elements in a top-level array?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by content is missing, it console.logs all of the json data i am moving in if i do `props.data`, but if i do `props.data.content.user_data[1]`, it returns undefined, even though it literally shows `props.data.content.user_data[1]` in the console if i do `props.data`

Comment: this is more like a concern in your ui, please share more of your jsx code, you should be putting a spinner/loader when data has not yet loaded

Answer (score 0):

Adding a ternary operator to make the component reload once the data comes in solved it:

`<p>Data: {props.data ? props.data.content.user_data[1] : "Data is loading..."}</p>`

I guess the component was loading before the JSON could load the whole way through.